# Passport user not set on Express session but is available on sockets handshake

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, node.js-connect, redistogo

I'm using Passport with NodeJS Express, Connect. The session store is RedisStore. I'm using the Forcedotcom strategy.

When I make a REST call to my Express server I always see a blank in the Passport section of req.session. Also, req.user is undefined:

```
{ cookie: ,
_expires: Tue Oct 29 2013 07:38:47 GMT+0000 (UTC),
httpOnly: true,
domain: '.DOMAIN' },
passport: {} }
```

However, the user is being set on my sockets object socket.handshake.user.

```
io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: express.cookieParser, //or connect.cookieParser
    key:          'expressSid',        //the cookie where express (or connect) stores its   session id.
    secret:        expressSecret,  //the session secret to parse the cookie
    store:         sessionStore,      //the session store that express uses
    fail: function(data, accept) {      // *optional* callbacks on success or fail
     accept(null, false);              
},
success: function(data, accept) {
  accept(null, true);
}
```

}));

Passport serialize and deserialize for a user object I store in Redis during authentication:

```
passport.serializeUser(function( user, done ) {

    done( null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function( id, done ) {

redis.hget("usersf:"+id, "data", function(err, data) {
    done( null, JSON.parse(data) );

});

});
```

Express connect middleware:

```
var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
                    client :redis,
                                        host: rtg.hostname,
                                        port: rtg.port,
                                        db: redisAuth[0],
                                        pass: redisAuth[1],
                                                  prefix: 'appsess:'
                                      });

appSecure.use(allowCrossDomain);
appSecure.use(express.cookieParser());
appSecure.use(express.bodyParser());
appSecure.use(express.methodOverride());
appSecure.set('port', port); 
appSecure.use(express.session({ secret: expressSecret, store: sessionStore, key:'expressSid', cookie: { maxAge : 604800000, domain:'.DOMAIN'}}));
appSecure.use(passport.initialize());
appSecure.use(passport.session());
appSecure.use(appSecure.router);
appSecure.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
appSecure.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized after rereading this that the cookie variable on the session object was blank and that might indicate a client side issue. Looking at my client side AngularJS REST service I realized that the parameter WithCredentials was set to false. Setting this to true resulted in the session cookie being sent and the user being set by Passport on req.user.

```
myApp.factory('RESTService',
function ($http) {
    return {
        get:function (url, callback) {
            return $http.get(url, {withCredentials:true}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    callback(data);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("failed to retrieve data");
                });
        }
    };
}
);
```